# What is this plant with red and yellow flowers on long thin stems?

Tags: identification, flowers

[image]

I saw this plant outside a restaurant in New Hampshire. What is it called?

Answer (score 1):

It's Cytisus scoparius and it might be the variety 'Lena', but there are various hybrids now in slightly differing colours. Average height and spread 1.5m x 1m,  likes light, sandy soil, full sun, hardy down to -20degC, no pruning other than a light clip over after flowering. These shrubs do not regrow from old wood; they are commonly known as Broom. Image here https://uk.pinterest.com/pin/405464772672189639/ - it's a Pinterest link, its the first photo on the page.